# How to Play a Sound in Certain value in IF statement? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

How to play a random sound in different if statements?
Example when will be in 0 to 25 then Play some Sound once or twice, when value (my slider) is in 25 to 40 play more sounds in the row... i wanna simulate breathing, but I think this script is too much to handle for me..

Sound is playing only once and only when i start game.
Looks like Unity read only first If statement and after that will nothing happening.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayingSoundsystem: MonoBehaviour {
    private AudioSource breath_sound;
    
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip[] breath_Clip;
    private AudioClip breath;
    
    public float volume_Min, volume_Max;
    public GameObject Textvalue;
    public Slider mainSlider;
    public GameObject Spotlight;
    public GameObject blur;
    
    private void Start() {
        breath_sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    
    private void Update() {
        Textvalue.GetComponent<Text>().text = mainSlider.value.ToString();
    
        if (Spotlight.GetComponent<Light>().enabled == false) {
            mainSlider.value += 1*Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else {
            mainSlider.value -= 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    
        if (mainSlider.value <= 25) {
            breath_sound.volume = Random.Range(volume_Min, volume_Max);
            breath_sound.clip = breath_Clip[Random.Range(0, breath_Clip.Length)];
            breath_sound.PlayOneShot(breath_sound.clip);
            //Play Random Sound from 13 different one's
        }
        if (mainSlider.value > 25 && mainSlider.value <= 40) {
            int index = Random.Range(0, breath_Clip.Length);
            breath = breath_Clip[index];
            breath_sound.clip = breath;
            breath_sound.Play();
        }
        if (mainSlider.value > 40 && mainSlider.value <= 60) {
            breath_sound.volume = Random.Range(volume_Min, volume_Max);
            breath_sound.clip = breath_Clip[Random.Range(0, breath_Clip.Length)];
            breath_sound.PlayOneShot(breath_sound.clip);
        }
        if (mainSlider.value > 60 && mainSlider.value <= 85) {
            breath_sound.volume = Random.Range(volume_Min, volume_Max);
            breath_sound.clip = breath_Clip[Random.Range(0, breath_Clip.Length)];
            breath_sound.PlayOneShot(breath_sound.clip);
        }
        if (mainSlider.value > 85 && mainSlider.value < 100) {
            breath_sound.volume = Random.Range(volume_Min, volume_Max);
            breath_sound.clip = breath_Clip[Random.Range(0, breath_Clip.Length)];
            breath_sound.PlayOneShot(breath_sound.clip);
        }
        if (mainSlider.value == 100) {
            
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Jumpscare")) {
            mainSlider.value += 5;
        }
    }
    
    public void SubmitSliderSetting() {
        Debug.Log(mainSlider.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: When is update() being called?

Comment: Update is called every frame so? i change it to Public and now Sounds are playing every frame..

Comment: Probably start by moving that code out of update() and into a new function. Then think of exactly when you want that code to be called.

Comment: Bryan other tips or hints? cheers i am still beginner

Comment: So right now your code will play a sound every time update() is called except when mainSlider.value  == 100. So when do you want a sound to actually play? A random number of seconds between 20 and 30 or something?

Comment: I wanna play sound in  0<25  from 1 to 3 different sounds, then 25<40 same thing here + playing random sounds and i will add different conditions...

Comment: You just explained what you want to do: play a sound dependent on a value. What you haven't said is **when** you want to. Maybe something like in this example: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html look at the timer variable

Comment: Stack overflow can be pretty strict so try to be specific in your question good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want to repeat your sounds you need to make sure that Loop is enabled on these Audio Sources.

[image: Loop]

---

Now that we don't need to call the sounds each frame we can instead just call them if the main slider value has been changed.

To achieve that we first need to get the currentValue from the mainSlider in our Start Method and then just check in the Update Method if the value is still equal to that current Value or if it has changed.

**Detecting Value Change:**

```cs
[SerializeField]
private AudioClip[] breath_Clip;

private AudioSource breath_sound;
private float currentValue = 0f;
private Text sliderText;
private Light spotLight;

private void Start() {
    // Get AudioSource of this component
    breath_sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
 
    // Getting start sliderValue
    currentValue = mainSlider.value;

    // Getting refernce to the Text Component of Textvalue.
    sliderText = Textvalue.GetComponent<Text>();

    // Getting reference to the Light component of SpotLight.
    spotLight = Spotlight.GetComponent<Light>();    

    // Setting text equal to the start slider Value
    sliderText.text = mainSlider.value.ToString();
}
    
private void Update() {
    // Update value when the light is deactivated/activated
    if (spotlight.enabled == false) {
        mainSlider.value += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else {
       mainSlider.value -= 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // Getting current sliderValue
    float value = mainSlider.value;

    // Check if the sliderValue has changed
    if (currentValue != value) {
        // Set currentValue to the correct Value
        currentValue = value;
        ValueChangedCallback(value);
    }
}
```

---

Now that we created the dectection of changes to our mainSlider Value we can make the function that changes the audioClip as well as the text depending on the current slider Value.

**ValueChangedCallback Method:**

```cs
private void ValueChangedCallback(float value) {
    // Setting text equal to the current slider Value
    sliderText.text = value.ToString();

    // Define clip that should be played (default is 0)
    int clipIndex = 0; 

    // Define volume clip should be played at (increase when the slider Value is higher)
   float volume = 10f;

    // Play different breath track depending on current slider Value
    if (value <= 25) {
        volume =  10f;
        clipIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (value > 25 && value <= 40) {
        volume = 15f;
        clipIndex = 1;
    }
    // Do the same for all the other possibilities ...

    breath_sound.volume =  volume;
    breath_sound.PlayOneShot(breath_Clip[clipIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathew you are such a big help , love people like you thank you for the respond soon as I will come back from work I will start coding you are a Star !

Comment: No problem hope it helps and solves your problem :D.

Comment: i changed it a lot but you give me an idea and now it is working!

Comment: No problem if it helped could you mark it as the answer.